# rmpbuild: tar inside another folder in the SOURCE folder

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm looking for a way to have my tar inside another folder in the SOURCE folder. Is there a way to do it?
I tried using:

```
Source:         another_folder/%{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
```

but I get:

```
error: Bad source: /tmp/rpm/SOURCES/rpm.tar.gz: No such file or directory
```

Comment: he is clearly not using your `Source` definition. What are you using inside the `%prep` stage? Try using `%setup -q` inside the `%prep` stage

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. Rpmbuild will use just basename of the file. You can use even URL as Source0 - and this is in fact often used. E.g

```
Source0: https://some.domain.com/download/%{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
```

And because rpmbuild will just use the basename - this works. I think most people welcome this as nice feature. On the other hand - your scenario is not possible.